# How can I load access data if this data has length=0?

Tags: asp-classic, ms-access-2003

I am loading data from access db but i have a problem with columns that don´t have lenght.
Here is asp code:

```
sql= "select * from clientes where usuario_clientes="+id_usuario
        rs.Open sql, oConn
        while not rs.EOF    
            nombre=rs.Fields("Nombre_clientes")
            dni=rs.Fields("dni_clientes")
            mail=rs.Fields("mail_clientes")
            domicilio=rs.Fields("direccion_clientes")
            cp=CStr(rs.Fields("cp_clientes"))
            poblacion=rs.Fields("poblacion_clientes")           
            movil=rs.Fields("movil_clientes")

            if not rs.Fields("observaciones_clientes") then
                observaciones=" "
            else
                observaciones=rs.Fields("observaciones_clientes")
            end if

            if not rs.Fields("telefono_clientes") then
                telefono=""
            else
                telefono=rs.Fields("telefono_clientes")
            end if


            fila="<tr><td>"+nombre+"</td><td>"+dni+"</td><td>"+mail+"</td><td>"+domicilio+"</td><td>"+cp+"</td><td>"+poblacion+"</td><td>"+telefono+"</td><td>"+movil+"</td><td>"+observaciones+"</td></tr>"
            response.Write(fila)
            rs.MoveNext
        wend
```

I tried to show lenght 0 string if this data doesn´t exist but it not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand, but MS Access is usually set-up to not allow zero-length strings, so these fields are likely to be null. Perhaps:

```
if IsNull(rs.Fields("telefono_clientes")) then
    telefono="--"
else
```

Comment: at the first thanks. But how can I distinct if that string has zero-length? I tryed if len(rs.Fields("telefono_clientes"))==0 but it doesn´t work

Comment: Do you mean if `rs.Fields("telefono_clientes")=""`? It will usually not work, because the field will be null. You can say `rs.Fields("telefono_clientes") & "" =""`, which will change nulls to "". Or `Trim(rs.Fields("telefono_clientes")) & ""=""`, which will include nulls, zero-length and space-filled.

Comment: the solution: if IsNull(rs.Fields("telefono_clientes")) then
     telefono=""
    else
     telefono=rs.Fields("telefono_clientes")
    end if